# Auto-incrementing from custom value in prisma + postgresql

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm using a prismia db client with postgresql and I'd like to start auto incrementing an integer field from 0 instead of 1. In other words, how can I write a model so that it starts from 0?

Here's the modal I have.

```
model SortableItem {
  id    String @id @default(uuid())
  name  String
  order Int @default(autoincrement())
}
```

With this implementation, when a record is inserted for the first time, the `order` starts from 1, but I'd like it to start from 0.

I know postgresql has `RESTART` to achieve this, but I couldn't find anything equivalent for prisma ORM syntax.

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_columnname_seq RESTART WITH 0;
```

Comment: It should be `ALTER SEQUENCE "tablename_columnname_seq" RESTART WITH 0;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible from the schema directly but you can add this to your migration SQL and it should work:

1. Create a migration using `prisma migrate dev --create-only`.
2. Edit the generated `.sql` file and add the above statement.
3. Run `prisma migrate dev`.

The following steps will alter the sequence.

Comment: I see. I was not aware of the `--create-only` flag. Thanks.

Comment: This is the most beautiful day of my life 